# Extra vertical space when using align and no numbering

Tags: spacing, numbering, amsmath, align, mathtools

I think I've found a small bug in the way the `showonlyrefs=true` option in `mathtools` works. Consider this semi-minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver og andet godt fra havet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % ingen numerering af equations

\begin{document}
%
Seems fine
\begin{align*}
    \Delta S &= \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{produkter})) - \sum(S^{\ominus}    (\text{reaktanter})) \\
    \Delta S &= (\SI{214}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + 2\cdot \SI{33}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) - (2\cdot \SI{27}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + \SI{6}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) \\
    \Delta S &= \SI{247}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}
\end{align*}
%
Not so fine
\begin{align}
    \Delta S &= \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{produkter})) - \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{reaktanter})) \\
    \Delta S &= (\SI{214}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + 2\cdot \SI{33}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) - (2\cdot \SI{27}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + \SI{6}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) \\
    \Delta S &= \SI{247}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

In the first set of equations, I've removed the numbering with the `*` sign, while in the second set I have not. However, I have the `showonlyrefs=true` option set in `mathtools` package, which usually removes all numbering of equations, unless it's being refered to. I would guess, that the long equations move the number to the next line, but somehow `mathtools` can't remove that space.

Is this a bug or am I missing something here? I rather like the way I can remove numbering when it's not needed, so I'd rather not go back to manually managing which equations I'd like to be numbered.

Comment: It's a problem with the length of the second equation: it's almost `\textwidth`, as you can check with the `showframe` option of `geometry. If you set, say, `hmargin=3cm`, it's OK.

Comment: i haven't run this through latex, but given the width of the second line, i think that your conclusion that a number for that line would require a line of its own is sound.  i'd send the example to the mathtools maintainer, lars madsen.

Comment: @Bernard Exactly, but the option given to ``mathtools`` should, in my opinion, work as \begin{align*}, aka remove the line where the number "should" be.

Comment: @ Argo: I agree with you, I was just suggesting a workaround. Such cases must be relatively rare.

Comment: I haven't seen that "feature" before. Something this wide really should be rewritten for readability. Mathtools take over the rendering of the eqn number. But not the measuring. Thus it fails.

Comment: I agree that the line is too wide, but there's little possibilities in improving readability. Such termodynamic calculation tend to get very large, so usually I split the line with the minus sign and align that with the equals (although that probably isn't the most elegant way either). Is there any way to make mathtools behave the way I'd like it to?

Comment: The problem is that `align` decides that the second line is too wide, so it must typeset the number in a lower position; the `showonlyrefs=true` option simply suppress showing the number, but it can't influence the decisions made by `align` about its position. You need to split that second line anyway, for example with `\begin{multlined}[t]`

Comment: I see. Is there still a way to make mathtools behave the way I'd like it to?

Answer (score 1):

The `autonum` package seems not to suffer from the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver og andet godt fra havet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
%
Seems fine
\begin{align}
    \Delta S &= \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{produkter})) - \sum(S^{\ominus}    (\text{reaktanter})) \\
    \Delta S &= (\SI{214}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + 2\cdot \SI{33}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) - (2\cdot \SI{27}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + \SI{6}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) \\
    \Delta S &= \SI{247}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}
\end{align}
%
Not so fine
\begin{align}
    \Delta S &= \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{produkter})) - \sum(S^{\ominus}(\text{reaktanter})) \\
    \Delta S &= (\SI{214}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + 2\cdot \SI{33}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) - (2\cdot \SI{27}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole} + \SI{6}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}) \\
    \Delta S &= \SI{247}{\joule\per\kelvin\per\mole}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that with the `autonum` package you should not use the `*`-variant of environments, just adding no `\label` is sufficient.

[image]