# Vertical spacing in mathtools

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

When using `mathtools` with the option `showonlyrefs` I find a spurious vertical spacing. I have found a [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203167) question but the issue there was a long equation, which is not my case. Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
a=b
\end{equation}
This is an equation %\refeq{eq}
\end{document}
```

If one uncomments `\refeq`, the vertical space after the equation is reduced. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use the `minimal` class for examples, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided?s=1|1.8970

Comment: Approved for your 1st question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until `mathtools` version 1.23 is released, here is a patch that fixes the issue

The tag needs to always have a non-zero width or else `equation` may add a blank line. But the processing branch for `showonlyref` did not cover all cases

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn

\xpatchcmd{\MT_extended_tagform:n}{
  \@ifundefined{MT_r_\df@label}{}
}{%
 \@ifundefined{MT_r_\df@label}{\kern1sp}
}{}{\typeout{patch failed}}

\xpatchcmd{\MT_extended_tagform:n}{
\@ifundefined{MT_r_\df@label}{\global\MH_set_boolean_F:n {manual_tag}}
}{%
\@ifundefined{MT_r_\df@label}{\global\MH_set_boolean_F:n {manual_tag}\kern1sp}
}{}{\typeout{patch failed}}

\MHInternalSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Had to wait five years but it was worth it `:-)`

Comment: @campa I don't think I ever saw your question

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a `feature' of the problematic equation environment (see various posts on this site).  It disappears in the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\label{eq}
a=b
\end{gather}
This is an equation %\refeq{eq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good point! That is reason, why in my document  I usually use `gather` instead `equation`.

Answer (score 3):

The `autonum` package seems to be better at it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autonum}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
a=b
\end{equation}
This is an equation \eqref{eq1}.
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
a=b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `align` instead of `equation`

```
\begin{align}\label{eq}
    a &= b
\end{align}
This is an equation \refeq{eq}
```