# How to automatically avoid numbering all non referenced equations in latex?

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, numbering

I am writing a fairly long document and decided to pospone the decision about which equations to number, so I just wrote all my math in `\begin{equation}` enviroment, planning to add all the due asterisks in a second time.

I have labeled most equations and referenced them fairly often through the document.

I was wondering if there was any way to tell Latex to check which equations I have referenced elsewhere in the document and to automatically add the asterisks to all the equations that I have not used elsewhere because that would save me some time.

EDIT: `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}` fix did not work it just renumbered every reference to 1.1 and removed all the numbers beside equations. `autonum` instead removed all the numbers beside equations and replaced every reference with "**??**"

Answer (score 7):

Load package `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`) and add to your preamble:

```
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
```

Comment: You could mention also `autonum`. With this `mathtools` option [I've had my problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257928/82917) (My first question on the site `:-)`)

Comment: thank you very much you probably saved me an afternoon

EDIT: mathtools did not work it just renumbered every reference to 1.1 and removed all the numbers beside equations

Comment: i am using \ref

Comment: i replaced everything with '\eqref' and it worked.
thank you very much, big ups

Comment: You even can  load `cleveref` and type `\cref`, it will save you some typing (to be loaded *after* `hyperref`)